# Spring-cloud-contract set state

Tags: spring, junit, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to use scenarios (aka states) when verifying contracts on a consumer side. The scenarios are defined in spring cloud contracts by using number prefix for groovy scripts like it is said in documentation:

```
my_contracts_dir\
    scenario1\
        1_login.groovy
        2_showCart.groovy
        3_logout.groovy
```

As a result in wiremock json files I see that "newScenarioState" field are added, like this:

```js
{
  "uuid" : "34a829d1-adf4-41e4-b7d9-6ee66d7de8bc",
  "request" : {
    "url" : "/foo/demo",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "[{\"model\":{\"address\":\"Address\",\"name\":\"String\"}}]",
    "headers" : {
      "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
  },
  "scenarioName" : "Scenario_contracts",
  "requiredScenarioState" : "Step2",
  "newScenarioState" : "Step3"
}
```

The question how can I use this states when writing consumer integration test? Let's say I want the stab switches to state "Step3". How can I do it in consumer integration test?

Additional info: in consumer integration test (which is Junit test) I use StubRunnerRule instead of @AutoConfigureStubRunner. So I expect via this rule I can use some api to set state for a stub. But I did not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the server to a state by sending proper requests. If you want to switch the state from step1 to step2 then you have to send a proper request that triggers the step1 to step2 transition. In the example that you're showing you'd have to send requests that would do the transition from step1 to step2 and then from step2 to step3. In the latter case it would be a GET message as described in the WireMock stub. Remember though that then you're going in to the state related issues. Your stub will be shared between your tests - remember to pass the @DirtiesContext annotation on your tests to ensure that a new context will be spawned and you will be able to set up your stubs in the way you want.

Last remark - try not to use stateful tests and just split the problem into separate steps that you can tests independently. That way you can test those things fast and in parallel. For contract testing you don't necessarily need any state on the stub side.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin. Yes I got your point regarding stateful tests while I was watching several your talks in internet.
But if I need to test how my consumer service reacts when producer returns different responses on the same request. Lets say consumer service is a shopping cart. I want to run consumer test when shopping cart is empty and when there are some items in it. What could you recommend for this case?

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: No problem! I would separate the steps and separately test the request response communication. Remember that contact tests are not supposed to duplicate your functionality. You want only to test whether you can actually properly communicate. So after separating the business logic from the infrastructure logic I would test the former by stubbing out any http communication and the former by separately checking the 3 different steps. Does it make any sense? :)

Comment: Also you can differentiate the request by body or headers. You can invent that if the name for a person is "fraud" then we can assume that we will switch the person to "fraud" state. That's how you can control the process